# How to create a UIView singleton in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to avoid create UIView like This:

```
let singleView = SingleView()
```

Here is How I create a SingleTon:

```
class SingleView:UIView {

    static let sharedInstance = SingleView()

    private init() {
        super.init(frame:CGRectZero)
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

However it will compile sucess.

Comment: I want add UIView to UIWindow, look like a system volume control. So I want create a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a view singleton is a bad idea, because a `UIView` instance will only have one `superView`, e.g. be subView of only one other view.

- If you use this only once, there is no benefit from sharing the instance.
- If you use it in different `UIViewController` instances, it will probably not behave as you expect.

Anyhow, you seem to not even want a singleton, which is good.

So, how about this?

```
class SingleView:UIView {
    init() {
        super.init(frame:CGRectZero)
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize without parameters in the constructor like you wanted all along.

PS: please note that constructors in swift always create new instances (or none at all). If you want to use a singleton, you hide the constructors and provide a factory-method (or a `static let` as you did).

Comment: I want add UIView to UIWindow, look like a system volume control. So I want create a singleton, Do you have a good idea? thank you.